# HTTP API call from Cobol DB2 program

Tags: http, cobol

As per the assignment I need to develop a Cobol DB2 program that calls HTTP requests to get the data from web application. Any help on how to make http calls from cobol program (Open source)? My google search didnt get right examples..

Thanks

Comment: Your COBOL program can [process JSON messages](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/parse-json-using-ibm-enterprise-cobol/) from a web front end and [create JSON messages](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=statements-json-generate-statement) to pass to a web front end.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert for reply. How the cobol program call look like with these parameters?..

Comment: You said it was an assignment.  What have you been taught?  I have not done anything like this, but I think your code has to be a CICS transaction that reads JSON from a message queue and writes JSON to either the same or a different message queue.

Comment: Your previous question (which you should have edited instead of asking a new one) contained the important detail that you want to use gnu cobol - which makes loads of difference with respect to doing HTTP requests and possibly JSON generation/parsing.